# How to make an IF ELSE condition in PHP and MySQL query with user LOGIN info

Tags: php, mysql

Good day! I really need someone's help here. I have a hard time thinking about how to execute the right code.

I am creating a website with a single index.php file wherein it consists of 2 headers. I am using "include" statement for the header to be called on the index. "header1.php" is the default header for the guests of the websites which also consist of "LOGIN" button. While "header2.php" is the header for those who have logged in their account and have a "LOGOUT" button.

The problem is, when the guest visits the websites, the websites will show the default header which is "header1.php". And when the user log in to his/her account, the "header2.php" will show. How should i suppose to call the header? What condition should I write inside the if else statement? It will probably need an access to the MySQL Database for the user's data.

Example:

```
<?php
if( user log in to his account ){

    include 'header2.php';

}else{

    include 'header1.php';
}
```

my log in script is:

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yfcgk_canlaon");

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from members WHERE USERNAME = '$username' and PASSWORD = '$password'");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($count <= 0 ){

    session_start();

    header("location:index.php?error");

}else{

    $_SESSION['user'] = 1;

    $_SESSION['username'] = ucwords($username);

    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You can do something like: if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] == 1) { include("header2.php"); } else { include("header1.php"); }

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be this

```
if ($_SESSION['user'] && $_SESSION['user'] == 1) {

  include 'header2.php';

}else{

  include 'header1.php';

}
```

Comment: Also you can use `isset()` function. `if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] == 1) {`

Comment: May be try: `if ($_SESSION && $_SESSION['user'] && $_SESSION['user'] == 1)` or `if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] == 1)`

Comment: Before this condition, you must also `session_start();`

Comment: but i got another problem. once i log out, the header2.php remains with LOGOUT button. it should be the default header1.php will be shown

Comment: <a href = "index.php">Logout </a>

Comment: When you log out you should `$_SESSION['user'] = 0;` or `unset($_SESSION['user']);` or `session_unset();`

Comment: <a href = "index.php" <?php unset($_SESSION['user']); ?>>Log out </a>